# GPS is on, yet LocationManager returns null

Tags: android

The GPS on my Android phone is on, supported by the fact that :

```
location_manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

returns true.

Yet, the following line :

```
 Location location = location_manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ;
```

returns null.

What could be the reason ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should requestLocationUpdates and wait for the first one.